# Ubuntu 16.04, how to use ATI graphics card instead of Intel?

Tags: drivers, graphics, radeon, amd-graphics, hybrid

I'm pretty new to the whole Linux thing so here is my problem. I have a hybrid system Intel/ATI:

```
lspci | grep -i vga
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Mars [Radeon HD 8730M]
```

I have the feeling that only the Intel graphics is used since the feeling when dragging a window around for example is very sluggish.

I tried to go by [this article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics) and set

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash radeon.modeset=1"
```

but it did not seem to make a difference.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: You need to install the ATI(AMD) Catalyst Control Center (Graphics Driver) to use the dedicated graphics card. Using that even you can switch the graphics for particular application. Just google it for more details..

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i think these are not available for 16.04 right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ATI proprietary drivers will not be available for 16.04. You can use the open source driver (included in Ubuntu). Problem is open source drivers are far from stable or productive as the proprietary Catalyst at this point. There will be a setback in performance for the time being. We can only hope for better drivers soon.
So to answer the question: You ARE currently using your ATI.
To be sure put this into terminal:
`lspci -nnk | grep -i vga -A3 | grep 'in use'`

for example the output can be
if the open source Radeon driver is used:

`Kernel driver in use: radeon`

if the proprietary Fglrx driver(not available in 16.04) is used:

`Kernel driver in use: fglrx_pci`

Comment: Oh i see. Seems like im using the driver indeed, i thought it might be somehow broken because of the bad performance... i guess i'll simply have to wait and see if performance will get better over time when the drivers are updated.

lspci -nnk | grep -i vga -A3 | grep 'in use'
 
Kernel driver in use: i915
 
Kernel driver in use: radeon

Comment: I got to the same problem and reverted to 14.04 cause of FGLRX driver(i can play League of legends on 300fps with i3 +7790 with it). Until better times this will be the option i guess.